# javascript all possibilited seed passphrase

Tags: javascript, seed

i want a javascript function to find 3 missing seed words
from bip39 seed phassphrase
i have my words list ... but i dont know the right place of words

so i need a function in javacsript to generate all possibilited

lets say I have wordlist1 = my wordlist
and I have wordlist2 = English wordlist

I know last word

how to generate a loop () for each possibility ?
or
maybe to create all possibilities and put "?" and then replace "?" with a English dictionary one by one

Comment: Please add your words and code to your question

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What do you mean by seed words?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.